# Rails: Are Controller Strong Params Necessary with Session Authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, strong-parameters

Rails developers should be familiar with the typical strong-parameter construction:

```
private
def object_params
  params.require(:object).permit(:object_data, ...)
end
```

I've been looking through the code of a project I'm starting to work on, and I noticed that this isn't used anywhere. Instead on creation they simply use `params[:object]` and stop there.

This worried me, so I decided to send some POSTs through **curl** to create "Objects" on my own. They were each getting denied (thankfully) because the Application's session required User permissions. And from Curl there was none.

So I figured it wasn't an issue as you would have to log in anyway, but I still feel uncomfortable because of the lack of strong parameters.

Is the Application still vulnerable? Should I add the strong params just in case?

---

- Looking through the gems, I feel like *Devise* is the only one that would have any effect here. 
   Still uncertain though.

Comment: As described in [Rails Controller docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), strong parameters are for protecting mass assignment to a model. They have nothing to do with using parameters individually unless you program for that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on your application. If every authenticated user has admin permissions, or their permissions are being checked elsewhere, then strong params aren't necessary provided that everyone with those permissions should be able to write to any attribute.

Personally, I would use strong parameters no matter what. It's convention, and it conveys the intended use of the controller. Even when all attributes are game, you can still use permit! to convey that.